# How to merge variables YEAR and MONTH in a propper way (in R)?

Tags: mysql, r, date

I have got a table `TRADES` with variable `YEAR (Y2015,Y2016)` - as factor and `MONTH` (1,2,3...) - as `integer`. My goal is to create new variable `DATE` (2015-12 for example). How should I act to solve this issue in R?

```
YEAR: Y2015, Y2016, Y2016, Y2015
MONTH: 1, 12, 2, 5
```

would like to create

```
DATE:
2015-1, 2016-12, 2016-2, 2015-5
```

Comment: Tag your question with the language you are referring to and you will get more/better answers.

Comment: What language/context are you using ? I suppose this is some SQL, but in that case, which DMBS ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Usually, a table has no "variables", and `Y2015` looks additionally strange

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Try `paste(substr(as.character(YEAR), 2, 5), MONTH, sep = "-")`

Comment: Thank's Allan, that is exactly what I wanted:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be tackled in 2 different ways. There is a handy little package called `Zoo` that has a class that represents years and months that could be used if you want to keep that text format you like, while also being able to order the months and years by date. Or you can represent them as the start of every month by adding an 01 and converting to a standard date format.

```html
year <- factor(c("Y2015", "Y2016", "Y2016", "Y2015"))
month <- c(1, 12, 2, 5)
#change year to a text variable, (for ease of processing) and remove the Y
year <- as.character(year)
year <- gsub(pattern = "Y", replacement = "", x = year)
# I assume you want this to actually be a date type, lets convert to the text field you want
## paste the fields together

#2 ways of going about this

#Zoo Way
#Represent the data as a year mon class in R (good if you keep it in R)
chr_YYYY_MM <- paste0(year, "-", month)
library(zoo)
yearmon_YYYY_MM<- as.yearmon(x = chr_YYYY_MM)
yearmon_YYYY_MM
# [1] "Jan 2015" "Dec 2016" "Feb 2016" "May 2015"
# You can keep it like this as long as you keep it in R

# you can change it back to a date object easily too: (if you need to upload back to sQL and keep it as a date)
as.Date(as.yearmon(yearmon_YYYY_MM))
# [1] "2015-01-01" "2016-12-01" "2016-02-01" "2015-05-01"

# Base R way
# You would need to append a 01 to the end of it
chr_date <- paste0(year, "-", month, "-", "01")
formated <- as.Date(x = chr_date, format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "UTC")
print(formated)
# [1] "2015-01-01" "2016-12-01" "2016-02-01" "2015-05-01"
class(formated)
# [1] "Date"
```

Comment: Very grateful for Your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want it this way?

```
DATE <- mapply(paste,gsub("\\D","",YEAR),MONTH,sep = "-")
```

or

```
DATE <- paste(gsub("\\D","",YEAR),MONTH,sep = "-")
```

such that

```
> DATE
     2015      2016      2016      2015 
 "2015-1" "2016-12"  "2016-2"  "2015-5"
```

**DATA**

```
YEAR<-factor(c( "Y2015", "Y2016", "Y2016", "Y2015"))
MONTH<- c(1, 12, 2, 5)
```